# Count the length of a float given string

Tags: c, string, floating-point, char, converters

Assume you have a variable `char s[30]`, and that `s` starts with a positive floating point number, e.g. 
`s = "15.016This is not a part of the float !";`

The character after the float could be anything but a digit.

The goal is to determine the number of characters which the float is represented with, e.g. |15.016| = 6.

I'm trying to write a simple code to do so, preferably without any external libraries.

I have:

```
int count_len(char *s)
{
   char tmp_buf[30];
   int integral_digits = sprintf(tmp_buf, "%d", atoi(s) );
   return integral_digits + sprintf(tmp_buf, "%d", atoi(s + integral_digits +1) );
}
```

This works for any number whose fraction does not contain a leading zero (works for 15.16, but not for 15.016).

How would you fix the function?

Comment: IRGS! your s string is longer than 30!

Comment: have you found the function "atof()"?

Comment: Hi @PeterMiehle - yes, I've tried, atof, but when you use `atof("1.6")`, the result is `1.60000001`, which ruins the count.

Comment: @PeterMiehle In that case, I would recommend `strtod()`/ `strtof()` over `atof()`. :-)

Comment: many paths lead to Rome

Comment: What about `1.0E20`? The `E` isn't a digit but it's part of the float. At least, that's how C will interpret it.

Comment: Hmmm  "trying to write a simple code to do so, preferably _without any external libraries_." and OP selects the answer that uses `sscanf()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not simply using `sscanf` with adhoc format specifiers?

Consider

```c
sscanf("15.01336This is not a part of the float !", "%*f%n", &len);
```

The `%*f%n` means

- `%*f` read a float number **but don't store** it anywhere, just consume it.
- `%n` store the number of **consumed characters** so far.

A working example

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int len;

    sscanf("15.01336This is not a part of the float !", "%*f%n", &len);

    printf("%d\n", len);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: better to initialize `int len = 0` in case no FP conversion occurs.

Answer (score 2):

C is for hacking, so why not write your function on the fly, like:

```
size_t floatlenghth(char *s)
{
  size_t len = 0;
  short found_dot = FALSE;
  while ((*s >= '0' && *s <= '9') || (*s == '.' && !found_dot)) {
    len += 1;
    if (*s == '.') found_dot = TRUE;
    s++;
  }
  return len;
}
```

to make things complicated,

- you have to take a look at the locale (like ',' for decimal-separator).

  .... char dottype = getdottypeforlocale();

  .... if (*s == dottype)
- how do you want to count leading zeros and trailing zeros after a dot (f.e. "001.200blubber" is it length 7 or is it length 3?)

  ... s = skipleadingzeros(s);

  ... /*inside while*/ if (found_dot && *s == '0') counttrailingzeros++; else counttrailingzeros = 0;

  ... /*after while*/ len -= counttrailingzeros;
- scientific notation: 1.22E01

  ... after the while() take a look iff *s = 'E' and the next two chars are digits, then add 3
- thousender-mark(s), like in 1'234.56 (is this anywhere valid?) or 1,234.56 (english) or 1.234,56 (german) or 1,234,567.89

Comment: `isdigit` might be useful

Comment: @LubomírSedlář in this example I wanted to show, that you can do it without ANY library-function. if you want to use library-function (which I do recommend!), the other answerers have shown how to do it.

Comment: Many devs cannot actually write code, only sling together library calls:)

Comment: @MartinJames That's true! But also many devs fail to write general code. When you first learn programming emulating library functions make you proud, when you have a lot of years of wide spread programming you start thinking: What if the user locale use `,` instead of `.`? What if the float use scientific notation? What if the string encoding is UTF8 or some est asia encoding? So you becomes proud of writing and using precise interfaces (like library functions). I concord with you however, you absolutely need to go through the code-by-your-self phase to call your self a dev :)

Answer (score 1):

If you have an input string of the pattern,

```
  "15.016This is not a part of the float !";
```

as you mentioned in your question, I would recommend you to make use of the function [`strspn()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strspn) or [`strcspn()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strcspn), available in `string.h` to find out the *length* of the  leading `float` type.

If you use `strspn()`, you can set the `accept` to all the digits and dot`.`.

You don't need an *external* library to use them. They are part of standard `C` and `glibc`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer ! Just a small problem though -- what happens if there's another dot after the float? I wrote `strspn(s, "0123456789.")`, but this doesn't work for `s=15.016.3snjk`. I can call strspn another time if `s[strspn(s, "0123456789")] == '.'`, but was wondering if there's a better way. Thanks again !

Comment: @RB Sadly there is no _direct_ way to get that, You need to roll your own function, maybe mixing up a couple of library function.

Comment: Hmmm... dear downvoter, care to leave a comment here?

Comment: @Sourav Ghosh NMDV, but OP did say "preferably without any external libraries" which would indicate a preference of not using `strspn() strcspn()`.

Answer (score 1):

```
int count_len(char *s){
    int len = 0;
    sscanf(s, "%*lf%n", &len);
    return len;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`strtod` is ideal for this:

```
char *endOfFloat;
double val = strtod( str, &endOfFloat );
size_t len = (size_t) endOfFloat - str;
```

This assumes the float part of the string is well-formed and representable as a `double`.

If that's not the case you'll need a different approach.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this in 3 minutes. It has a couple of bugs though, it counts zeros on the right of the number, for example. It something you can fix yourself :)

```
int count_len(const char *s)
{
    const int sz = strlen(s);
    int sz_of_float = 0;
    bool dot = false; // to avoid double dots like ".."
    for(int i = 0; i < sz; i++)
    {
        if(s[i] >= '0' && s[i] <= '9')
            sz_of_float++;
        else if(s[i] == '.' && dot == false)
        {
            dot = true;
            sz_of_float++;
        }
        else
            return sz_of_float;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you would think about the algorithm for writing such a function.

1. Set the count to zero.
2. If the first character is a non-zero digit, set the count to 1. Otherwise, exit and return zero.
3. Starting from the next character, read in the maximum number of digits before hitting a non-digit character or the end of the string, incrementing the count each time.
4. If the end of the string is reached, exit and return the count. Otherwise, if the character is a period, add 1 to the count.
5. Starting from the next character after the period, read in the maximum number of digits before hitting a non-digit character or the end of the string, incrementing the count each time.
6. Return count.

Sample code:

```
int countDigits(char const * str)
{
    int count = 0;
    int i;

    if (str == NULL) return 0;
    for (i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        if (isdigit(str[i]))
            count++;
        else
            break;
    }
}

int countFloatChars(char const * str)
{
    int count = 0;

    if (str == NULL) return 0;
    if (str[0] == '\0') return 0;

    if ((str[0] < '1') || (str[0] > '9')) return 0;

    count = 1;
    count += countDigits(str + count);

    if ((str[count] == '\0') || (str[count] != '.')) return count;

    count++;
    count += countDigits(str + count);

    return count;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Without using C libraries, to look for `(digits).(digits)` where at least 1 digit is found:

```
size_t float_length(const char *s) {
  const char *p = s;
  int digit_count = 0;

  // could add tests for white-space, +, - here        

  while (*p >= '0' && *p <= '9') {
    s++;
    digit_found = 1;
  }
  if (*p == '.') {
    p++;
    while (*p >= '0' && *p <= '9') {
      p++;
      digit_found = 1;
    }
  }
  if (digit_found) return (size_t) (p - s);
  return 0;
}
```

Nothing fancy.